# Multilanguage In Drupal

Tags: multi-sites, i18n-l10n

Now, I'm trying to translate my content pages into Burmese language. But, the problem is there is no language option appear in "Publishing Options" Tab. I enabled Content translation, Locale and Multilingual Internationalization, Variable modules. Although I enabled all these modules and clear the cache, it still doesn't appear. 
Please, help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If your language is not already added, you can do it in this interface **admin/config/regional/language/add**
2. You have to check that your new language is activated in the languages manager **admin/config/regional/language**
3. Check that this modules are activated : **Local, i18n**
4. In your content type manager, check that **multilingual settings** tab exist
5. In this tab, choose the elements suitable for your case
6. In **Publishing options** tab, check that multilingual support is activated

Answer (score 1):

**Enabling entity translation for a content type**

With Entity Translation enabled for "Node", you can set the translation mode (Entity Translation or Content Translation) for each Content Type. To enable translation mode for a particular content type, you need to edit the content type and click on the 'Publishing options' tab and choose under Multilingual support:

[see the resource here](https://www.drupal.org/taxonomy/term/34058?page=1)